# Displaying taxonomy on DotNetNuke Page

Tags: dotnetnuke, taxonomy, tagging

I've added tags to the pages on my dnn site and I would like to display a simple list of the tags that the page is assigned to at the bottom of the page.

I'm using DNN 6 and I've read that this is possible by adding some lines to the skin file.
I've added

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="TAGS" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Tags.ascx" %>
```

and `<dnn:tags runat="server" id="dnnTags" />` as per online suggestions

When I view the page there are no tags, and in the source the only thing outputted is an empty div `<div class="horizontal"></div>`
This does suggest that the tags.acsx is being called ok

I thought maybe tags weren't working, but when I put a ContentList module on the page and visit the page with ?Tag=test appended to the link it does pick up all the pages and modules with that tag, including the page I am testing.

Has anyone experienced anything like this before?

Thanks

---

I've now found that removing the below section of code from tags.ascx.cs allows the page to display the list of tags

```
 string resultsUrl = Null.NullString;
var objModules = new ModuleController();
int searchTabId = 0;
ModuleInfo SearchModule = objModules.GetModuleByDefinition(PortalSettings.PortalId, "Search Results");
if (SearchModule == null)
{
return;
}
else
{
searchTabId = SearchModule.TabID;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to the addition of the skin object.  Part 1

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="TAGS" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Tags.ascx" %>
```

Then you need to actually add it to the page where you need it.

```
<dnn:TAGS id="mytags" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Ah sorry the box stripped some of my code
I do have both those lines in and all that is outputted to replace the runat server line is a blank div with the class 'horizontal'